# How to left join based on specific conditions in Python SQL?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, left-join

I have 2 dataframes, `df1` and `df2` like this:

df1=

```
person_id 
10001
...
10900
```

df2=

```
person_id month_1 place_1
10001       255     X
... 
10900       2111    Y
10900       500     X
10900       200     X
```

I want to left join df2 on df1 only where `place_1 is X` and the final value as the `sum(month_1)`
Like this :

newdf=

```
person_id month_1 place_1
10900       700      X
```

So far, I've thought of constructing my sqlite3 code as follows :

```
import sqlite3
conn=sqlite3.connect(':memory:') 
crsr=conn.cursor()

qry='''
SELECT df1.*
FROM df1
left join df2 on sum(month_1)
WHERE UPPER(place_1) like '%X%'
group by df2.person_id
on df1.person_id = df2.person_id;
''' 

new_df=pd.read_sql(qry,conn)
```

What is going wrong in my query approach? How should I implement my query logic correctly?

I'm learning how to use SQL to manage my data within Python. Any help would be greatly helpful!

Comment: "dataframes" is a strange name. We call this **tables**. It looks like `df1` is your person table containing one row per person (ID, name, etc.) while `df2` can contain several rows per person month and place. Yes?

Comment: sorry. Tables. And yes, ```df1``` contains several rows with only one column (ID) and ```df2``` contains several rows with 3 columns (person, monthly amount, and place)

Comment: What about `person_id = 10001` ? Why isn't it in resultset?

Comment: Because ```person_id =10001``` is not there in ```df2```. It is possible for ```df1``` and ```df2``` to have different ```person_id```. My final table should only have the ```person_id``` common to both. Sorry if my question lacked clarity

Comment: So, the title "How to left join ..." makes no sense at all, because you want the opposite (only persons that are in *both* tables). A left outer join selects rows from one table even if the other table *doesn't* contain a match. I suggest you change your request title.

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question right, you are looking for all records in df2 with a place like X summed up and if that person has got some records in df1 then pull those as well.

To do that the following would get you the record set. (While aggregating the non-grouped columns should be in a aggregating function,such as MAX or MIN etc)

```
   SELECT df2.person_id
         ,sum(df2.month_1)
         ,max(df1.person_name) 
     FROM df2
LEFT JOIN df1 
       ON df2.person_id=df1.person_id
    WHERE UPPER(df2.place_1) like '%X%'
 GROUP BY df2.person_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your mistake:

```
left join df2 on sum(month_1)
```

ON must be followed a condition on which to join rows. `sum(month_1)` is not a condition, but a single value.

And while, say `sum(month_1) > 0` is a condition, it wouldn't work either, because you are joining single rows, and `sum(month_1)` is not a row's value, but an aggregation over several rows.

You have `on df1.person_id = df2.person_id` later, but the `ON` clause belongs with the `JOIN`, not at the end of the query.

What you want is to *select* `SUM(df2.month_1)`, so put it in the `SELECT` clause. The following query gives you all `df1` rows along with their `month_1` sum (or null, when there are no `df2` entries for the person).

```
SELECT df1.*, SUM(df2.month_1)
FROM df1
left join df2 ON df2.person_id  = df1.person_id
WHERE UPPER(df1.place_1) = 'X'
GROUP BY df1.person_id;
```

I don't know whether SQLite supports grouping by a key and selecting its functional dependent columns (`df1.*`), though. If you only want to show `df1.person_id` then you should replace `df1.*` by `df1.person_id`. If you want more `df1` columns and SQLIte doesnt allow `df1.*`, then you may want to aggregate before joining (which I consider good style anyway):

```
SELECT df1.*, d2.total
FROM df1
left join 
(
  SELECT person_id, SUM(month_1) AS total
  FROM df2
  GROUP BY person_id
) d2 ON d2.person_id  = df1.person_id 
WHERE UPPER(df1.place_1) = 'X';
```

Comment: I'll leave this answer in, because it answers your original question how to outer join df2 to df1 and get the sums. As it shows now that you want the opposite of an outer join, use Michał Turczyn's (now corrected) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try below, it doesn't join data, just filters by place and IDs in `df1`:

```
select person_id, sum(month_1) from df2
where place_1 = 'X' and
      exists(select 1 from df1
             where person_id = df2.person_id)
group by person_id
```

or using `in`:

```
select person_id, sum(month_1) from df2
where place_1 = 'X' and
      person_id in (select person_id from df1)
group by person_id
```

Comment: hi, both the codes just filters out one ```person_id``` with the ```sum(month_1)``` for all of the people with ```place_x == 'X' ```. To elaborate, I got only one row which contains  the ```person_id``` of the person that matched first, and against that, the ```sum(month_1) ``` for all the people whose ids match in df1 & df2

Comment: @Throwawayindi I don't quite understand. Did you try my suggestions? If so, are they correct? If not, what is wrong with the result you get?

Comment: I did. But I'm only getting one row. What I want is multiple rows with all of the common ```person_id``` in ```df1``` & ```df2``` with their respective ```sum(month_1) ``` against them, only if the ```place_1 is 'X' ```

Comment: @Throwawayindi It will give you all matching `person_id`s

Comment: But I'm only getting one ```person_id```. Only a single row

Comment: @Throwawayindi In both approaches? Inspect the data, if you have correct IDs.

Comment: The problem is that you forgot the `GROUP BY` clause in both queries: `group by person_id`.

Comment: @Throwawayindi I updated queries, as there were major mistake there. Can you try now?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want all the rows of `df1` and this is why you use a `LEFT` join.
So the condition `UPPER(df2.place_1) LIKE '%X%'` should be set in the `ON` clause and not in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT df1.person_id, SUM(month_1) AS month_1, MAX(place_1) place_1
FROM df1 LEFT JOIN df2 
ON df1.person_id = df2.person_id AND UPPER(df2.place_1) LIKE '%X%'
GROUP BY df1.person_id;
```

If instead of `NULL`s you want `0`s in the results for the non matching rows then change `SUM(month_1)` to:

```
COALESCE(SUM(month_1), 0)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d68atSnkhTSgjpwidTq5XW/1).
Results:

```
| person_id | month_1 | place_1 |
| --------- | ------- | ------- |
| 10001     | 255     | X       |
| 10900     | 700     | X       |
```